# How to get SSID and pswd of hidden network over ethernet on CMD

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, cmd.exe, ethernet

I have a router that the network is hidden, and I do not know the SSID or pswd. Instead, I connect it manually using an ethernet cable. How can I get the SSID and pswd over ethernet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connected via Ethernet, you should be able to log into the router. The IP address to connect to the router is usually 192.168.1.1 or 10.0.0.1. For my Cox router it was different, so check what the IP is for your model.

The default login is usually "admin", and the default password is usually "admin", "password", or blank. Once logged in, you should be able to find information on the Wi-Fi SSID. I was also able to see the Wi-Fi Passkey as well.

Comment: For me it was http://192.168.2.1.